# Searchview overlaps the other view of the custom action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview, android-appcompat

I have implement the custom action bar using appcompat v7 support library.
For that i have created the custom layout which have the desired view.
I have also placed the SearchView in the custom layout also.

Finally i got the desired output as shown below.[image]

**Problem ::**

when i click on the searchview the view overlaps over the other view of the layout which looks very ugly.

[image]

I want to behave searhview normally like the blow screen shot..

Kindly let me know where i am wrong..

Any suggestion/snippet will be helpful.

**CustomActionBar Layout ::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAppIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAppName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgAppIcon"
        android:text="Test App"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgOVerflow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_overflow" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/imgsearchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgOVerflow"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        yourapp:iconifiedByDefault="true"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.removeAllTabs();
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
 getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar_home);getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

 ImageView imgOverFlowMenu = (ImageView) getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.imgOVerflow);
```

Comment: You need to adjust your views with proper alignment. Otherwise LinearLayout with weight is best approach.!!

Comment: Are you trying to make a custom `ActionBar` or `Toolbar`? You should use the SearchView in your menu.xml. It is apart of the options menu.

Comment: Any solution for this?